# Manim: How to create a table with Tex in it? and grid only in first line?

Tags: animation, math, manim

I'm making an animation for my Final Paper, and I couldn't insert the symbol of the real numbers, here is the code:

```
from manim import *

class SimpleAnimation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        table = Table([
            ["oi", "test1"],
            ["test2", "test3"],
            ["test4", "test5"]
            ])
        self.play(Write(table))
```

And other question: how do I do a table with the grid only in the first line? like this, but in latex:

```
class SimpleAnimation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tex = Tex(r"""\begin{tabular}{l l}
            $\mathbb{N}$ & $\ \mathbb{R}$\\
            \hline
            1 & \ 0,156739345...\\
            2 & \ 0,823478901...\\
            3 & \ 0,465809217...\\
            4 & \ 0,156439345...\\
            5 & \ 0,823478903...\\
            $\vdots$ & $\ \vdots$\\
        \end{tabular}""",
                font_size=70)
        self.play(Write(tex))
```

I know that I'm supposed to input a str class, and I'm inserting a Tex class

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that there is more than just one type of `Table` object in Manim? The `MathTable()` renders every item as a LaTeX string. In the `MobjectTable()` you can place any Manim object at any position:

```py
class SimpleAnimation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        table = MobjectTable([
            [Square(side_length=0.25), Text("test1")],
            [MathTex(r"\pi^3"), Tex("test3")],
            [Tex("test4"), Tex(r"test $5^2$")]
            ])
        self.add(table)
```

[image]

For your second question: so with "grid" you mean that you only want one horizontal line after the heading and no vertical lines?

```py
class SimpleAnimation3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        values = [
            [0.156739345],
            [0.823478901],
            [0.465809217],
            [0.156439345],
            [0.823478903],
        ]
        table = DecimalTable(
            values,
            row_labels = [MathTex(rf"{i}") for i in range(1,6)],
            col_labels = [MathTex(r"\mathbb{R}")],
            top_left_entry = MathTex(r"\mathbb{N}"),
            element_to_mobject_config={"num_decimal_places": 9, "show_ellipsis":True},
            v_buff=0.3,
        )
        table.remove(*table.get_vertical_lines())
        table.remove(*table.get_horizontal_lines()[1:])
        self.add(table)
```

[image]

For more and better help come to the Discord server [**Where can I find more resources for learning Manim?**](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim)